Gender-inclusive word to mean "manned" but not "crewed"?
I am looking for a gender-inclusive alternative to the word "manned" so that I can avoid mentioning a word that suggests someone’s gender.
I have read about crewed, but as they say there, it means

Provide (a craft or vehicle) with a group of people to operate it

I would like a word that indicates that people are on board as passengers, and thus the vehicle is not operated by them, as the vehicle is completely autonomous.
Currently I have

A manned, but unpiloted, vehicle.

and I'm considering

An autonomous vehicle with passengers.

but I'd like to find something less convoluted if possible. Merriam-Webster was not of much use.
Does such a word exist?

@Řídící passenger drone seems to fit, feel free to suggest it in an answer. "Uncrewed" does not seem to imply the possibility of passengers, does it?

MODERATOR WARNING: Do not suggest answers in comments. Answers go only in the answer box. Comments suggesting possible answers may be edited or deleted.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"I would like a word that indicates that people are on board as passengers, and thus the vehicle is not operated by them": manned does not indicate this, so you are not looking for a gender-inclusive synonym of manned.

Do you mean a gender-inclusive synonym of unmanned?

The title needs to be edited to better reflect the meaning of the question. "Manned", for something with passengers, implies "crewed".

@TinfoilHat no, "unmanned" implies no humans on board.

No, unmanned means not having an operator, pilot, or crew on board. You can have passengers and not have a crew. unmanned passenger vehicle ... autonomous passenger vehicle ... or autonomous bus (which inherently has passengers).

Along with "manned" and "crewed" is "staffed", but while the staff might not be operating the vehicle, they're working on it so I don't propose it as an answer. It seems more common than "crewed" in general, so worthy of a note, and perhaps a mention in the question as another close but not perfect word

Occupied
This is the word often used with items that have no moving parts (like a chair), or vehicles that aren't controlled by the passengers inside. For example, see Occupied Vehicle Tow?. Technically, a driver can be considered an occupant, but it would be very odd to use that word except when referring collectively (like in a High Occupancy Vehicle [HOV]).
Note that "manned" and "crewed" are nearly completely synonymous; both indicate there are people who are operating (or otherwise working on) the vehicle.

Wiktionary gives passenger as a verb with past tense and past participle passengered.
The OED also includes the verb:

transitive (in passive). Of a vessel or vehicle: to be occupied by passengers; to be occupied by or with (someone or something) as a passenger.

The OED's first citation is from Ladies Repository in April 1874

'Boats', and 'ships', sailing over impossible rivers and seas, rigged and manned, and cargoed and passengered..in ways fitted to make genuine sailors die of laughter.

This isn't in many other dictionaries as a verb, and isn't very widely used, but I can find it in some contexts e.g. car and motorsports.

"Geoff Hughes passengered for a leading German driver", Isle of Man Today headline, 13 Dec 2023


"Have you passengered in a Tesla? It's shithouse." (Reddit, 2022)

Reference: Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “passenger (v.),” July 2023, https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/7335225961.

“Manned” means that human beings are running it. “Populated” might work for passengers, whicj is of course what you’re talking about.
Also the vessel may be remotely controlled by human beings or it may be self-operating in some way.

Have you ever seen populated used this way?  To me, phrases like "a populated bus" or "the airplane was populated" seem unnatural.

@Juhasz No, we’d say “More than 20 passengers were on board” or one of a thousand variants thereof. But the OP wants a substitute for manned.
